# vs code error " you do not have an extension for debugging html, should we find the html extension in the marketplace?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I unable to run my html code on vs code they give a error you don’t have html debugger and recommend to download  I download 3-4 recommend extension from the list but nothing is working same error came, again and again, what should I do please suggest

Answer (score 0):

You have to download ElixirLS: Elixir support and debugger.

But if that doesn't work, download 'Live Server' and follow the instructions given. This should work. Also, live server does the changes automatically everytime you save!